# How to setup NavigationLink inside SwiftUI list

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-list, swiftui-navigationlink

I am attempting to set up a SwiftUI weather app. when the user searches for a city name in the textfield then taps the search button, a NavigationLink list item should appear in the list. Then, the user should be able to click the navigation link and re-direct to a detail view. My goal is to have the searched navigation links to populate a list. However, my search cities are not populating in the list, and I'm not sure why. In ContentView, I setup a list with a ForEach function that passes in cityNameList, which is an instance of the WeatherViewModel. My expectation is that Text(city.title) should display as a NavigationLink list item. How should I configure the ContentView or ViewModel to populate the the list with NavigationLink list items? See My code below:

ContentView

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    
    // Whenever something in the viewmodel changes, the content view will know to update the UI related elements
    @StateObject var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    @State private var cityName = ""

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {

            VStack {
                TextField("Enter City Name", text: $cityName).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.fetchWeather(for: cityName)
                    cityName = ""
                }, label: {
                    Text("Search")
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
                
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.cityWeather, id: \.id) { city in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(detail: viewModel)) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(city.cityWeather.name)
                                    .font(.system(size: 32))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                
                Spacer()
            }
            .navigationTitle("Weather MVVM")
        }.padding()
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
    }
}
```

ViewModel

```
import Foundation

class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    //everytime these properties are updated, any view holding onto an instance of this viewModel will go ahead and updated the respective UI
        
    @Published var cityWeather: WeatherModel = WeatherModel()
    
    func fetchWeather(for cityName: String) {

        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(cityName)&units=imperial&appid=<MyAPIKey>") else {
            return
        }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            // get data
            guard let data = data, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            
            //convert data to model
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cityWeather = model
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error)
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Model

```
import Foundation

struct WeatherModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    var id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var main: CurrentWeather = CurrentWeather()
    var weather: [WeatherInfo] = []
    
    func firstWeatherInfo() -> String {
        return weather.count > 0 ? weather[0].description : ""
    }
}

struct CurrentWeather: Codable {
    var temp: Float = 0.0
}

struct WeatherInfo: Codable {
    var description: String = ""
}
```

DetailView

```
import SwiftUI

struct DetailView: View {
    
    var detail: WeatherViewModel
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(detail.cityWeather.name)
                .font(.system(size: 32))
            Text("\(detail.cityWeather.main.temp)")
                .font(.system(size: 44))
            Text(detail.cityWeather.firstWeatherInfo())
                .font(.system(size: 24))
        }
        

    }
}

struct DetailView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        DetailView(detail: WeatherViewModel.init())
    }
}
```

Comment: sad to see you did not take my advice from your previous question, suit yourself.
You are not seeing the list of `NavigationLink` because you don't have anything in the list. 
Note that you should have `@Published var cityNameList = [WeatherModel]()` NOT 
`@Published var cityNameList = [WeatherViewModel]()`. 

In your `fetchWeather()` add the results (in the form of WeatherModel) to your `cityNameList`.

Comment: Thanks @workingdog! After adding ```@Published var cityNameList = [WeatherModel]() ```, it looks like WeatherModel will need to conform to identifiable. How can I do that?

Comment: use this: `struct WeatherModel: Identifiable, Codable { let id = UUID() ....}`. Don't worry this won't affect the json decoding (Xcode will warn you of that).

Comment: @workingdog I updated my code above to reflect your answer for my previous question (see the code above). I also tried passing viewModel.cityWeather into the ForEach on the list, but I am getting the following error: ```Generic struct 'ForEach' requires that 'WeatherModel' conform to 'RandomAccessCollection'```

Comment: @workingdog I implemented the fixes you suggested in the example below, but the city list items are still not populating in the list.

Comment: no you haven't. Just copy and paste my code (and yourkey) and it will work.

Comment: ah ok, @workingdog that works now, though I still need to dissect this a little bit. First off, how did you know to set WeatherModel as an array in ```@Published var cityNameList = [WeatherModel]()``` ?

Comment: In other words, why does WeatherModel need to be an array in order to work?

Comment: you wanted a list of city weather, an array is a perfect fit for this.
If this answer was helpful, please mark it as such.

Comment: @workingdog thanks! Also, here is another question I posted this morning, if/when you have a moment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69929253/how-to-configure-swiftui-openweathermap-app-to-search-for-name-of-city-with-mult

Comment: you may be interested in my "experiment" into using openweathermap.
I did a basic weather app (YAWA, for Yet Another Weather App) a long time ago.
You can find it here: https://github.com/workingDog/YAWA

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this example code, works well for me:

```
struct WeatherModel: Identifiable, Codable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String = ""
    var main: CurrentWeather = CurrentWeather()
    var weather: [WeatherInfo] = []
    
    func firstWeatherInfo() -> String {
        return weather.count > 0 ? weather[0].description : ""
    }
}

struct CurrentWeather: Codable {
    var temp: Float = 0.0
}

struct WeatherInfo: Codable {
    var description: String = ""
}

struct ContentView: View {
    // Whenever something in the viewmodel changes, the content view will know to update the UI related elements
    @StateObject var viewModel = WeatherViewModel()
    @State private var cityName = ""
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                TextField("Enter City Name", text: $cityName).textFieldStyle(.roundedBorder)
                Button(action: {
                    viewModel.fetchWeather(for: cityName)
                    cityName = ""
                }, label: {
                    Text("Search")
                        .padding(10)
                        .background(Color.green)
                        .foregroundColor(Color.white)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                })
                List {
                    ForEach(viewModel.cityNameList) { city in
                        NavigationLink(destination: DetailView(detail: city)) {
                            HStack {
                                Text(city.name).font(.system(size: 32))
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                Spacer()
            }.navigationTitle("Weather MVVM")
        }.navigationViewStyle(.stack)
    }
}

struct DetailView: View {
    var detail: WeatherModel
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Text(detail.name).font(.system(size: 32))
            Text("\(detail.main.temp)").font(.system(size: 44))
            Text(detail.firstWeatherInfo()).font(.system(size: 24))
        }
    }
}

class WeatherViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var cityNameList = [WeatherModel]()
    
    func fetchWeather(for cityName: String) {
        guard let url = URL(string: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=\(cityName)&units=imperial&appid=YOURKEY") else { return }
        
        let task = URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, _, error in
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            do {
                let model = try JSONDecoder().decode(WeatherModel.self, from: data)
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.cityNameList.append(model)
                }
            }
            catch {
                print(error) // <-- you HAVE TO deal with errors here
            }
        }
        task.resume()
    }
}
```